# How to set custom json field name for System.Serializable class?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, mono, deserialization

I'm obtaining that response from server:

```
{
    "auth_token": "062450b9dd7e189f43427fbc5386f7771ba59467"
}
```

And for accessing it I need to use same name as in original JSON.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TokenResponse
{
    public string auth_token; // I want to rename it to authToken without renaming corresponding field in json
    public static TokenResponse CreateFromJSON(string json) {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<TokenResponse>(json);
    }
}
```

How to rename TokenResponse.auth_token to TokenResponse.authToken without losing the functionality?

Comment: `[JsonProperty("auth_token")]public string AuthToken {get;set};` (if you are using Json.Net)

Comment: No, I'm using using Mono (Unity3d)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose this is a code for Unity. Unfortunately it does not seem to allow you to change the key name of JSON string out of box.

However [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html%20the%20documentation)  says you can use [NonSerialized] attribute to omit fields. So the following code might let you do what you want.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TokenResponse
{
    [NonSerialized]
    public string AuthToken;

    public string auth_token { get { return AuthToken; } }

    public static TokenResponse CreateFromJSON(string json)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<TokenResponse>(json);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work because Unity never serialized properties— so you're basically telling Unity's `JsonUtility` _“Don't look for a key named `"AuthToken"` because I specified `[NonSerialized]`; and don't look for a key named `"auth_token"` because it's a property.”_  See my answer below for a version that works _(I'll be happy to delete my answer if you'd rather update your answer. ;-D )_

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson is right, please update the answer

Answer (score 5):

[@Mike Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116524/how-to-set-custom-json-field-name-for-system-serializable-class#answer-47116683) is close to a good solution for Unity, but unfortunately doesn't quite work *(because [Unity never serializes C# properties](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html))*.

Here's a variation on his answer that does compile and work correctly in Unity *(tested in Unity 2018.3.1)*.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TokenResponse
{
    [SerializeField] private string auth_token;
    public string authToken { get { return auth_token; } }

    public static TokenResponse CreateFromJSON(string json) {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<TokenResponse>(json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`JsonDotNet`](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347) instead `JsonUtility`

Just do this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TokenResponse
{
    // what is `JsonProperty` see:https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm
    [JsonProperty("auth_token")] 
    public string authToken {set; get;} 

    public static TokenResponse CreateFromJSON(string json) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(json);
    }
}
```